# Grep: Using the w command?

Tags: grep

I'm needing some help please to find lines in a file that do not contain the whole word `a`. 
I have tried  with `grep -wv '\ba\b'` but had no luck.

Comment: Works fine for me. Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -v '\ba\b' file
```